# breeze EntityManager metadata load time issue

Tags: breeze

It's being quite slow loading the DOM of the application since loading of breeze metadata is quite slow. Is there any tips to make it load faster and optimize?

Please take a look at following link to see how much it affects loading time.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2781659/8-27-2013%201-02-38%20PM.jpg

Comment: Also I do not understand why it sends 6 metadata load requests for single entity manager service initialization!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with my code that it started querying breeze manager on load.

Breeze loads metadata if metadata is not available during query execution.

I changed my code such that no query fires until the metadata loads.

my code change follow.

during viewmodel load I invoke loadMetadata() function with callback supplied. once the metadata is loaded my callback method would fire initial query.

```
var manager;
var store;

function loadMetadata(callback)
{
  manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
  store = manager.metadataStore;
  store.fetchMetadata(serviceName, callback);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Loading metadata with breeze is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461142/loading-metadata-with-breeze-is-slow) for a tip.

But you have other issues. I can think of no reason why the same EntityManager INSTANCE would ask for same metadata twice. Perhaps you are creating a new EM each time? If that's what you want to do, you can share the same metedatastore across EMs.

You want to find out what is making it slow in the first place. I doubt that has anything to do with Breeze on either client or server.