# Loading metadata with breeze is slow

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, breeze

I'm using breeze to load some data from a remote SQL Server database in a MVC 4 application. The database has around 40 entities. The loading of metadata with breeze takes a lot of time: somewhere between 14s and 35 s even though the size is not that big: ~ 600 kb.

After the metadata is loaded the entities are fetched much faster. For example an entity of 2.5 Mb was loaded in 2.5s.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8eqv5ezqr1qqlp/loading.png

My question is:

Is there a reason why this loading is that slow and what would be a way to reduce the time of loading?

Comment: From the screenshot it seams that the problem is on the server. If this is what takes so long, then you can implement some caching mechanism on the server. Check how long it takes for the second client to fetch the metadata.

Comment: I tried to fetch the data with a second client but the time was the same. I was thinking maybe there is a way to store the metadata in a file in the application so I could avoid the call to the server.

Comment: You can store it in a static field as a string.

Comment: Thank you for the response!
Apparently it is not loading the metadata but the connection to the SQL server that is slow. Any suggestions for that?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajypwpgoyn8z24q/Capture.PNG

Comment: After some more research I found out that the Entity Framework is the one responsible with the delay. The bad part is that there doesn't seem to be a solution...

Comment: Are you sure you aren't recreating the database and seeding it or anything while you are loading the metadata"

Comment: The database is on Microsoft Azure Servers. From what I understood entity framework uses a lot of tome for the initial setup. Maybe the update to EF6 will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rarely ask the server for metadata once I get going. I quickly export the metadata from an EntityManager's metadata store and dump that into a JavaScript file as a global variable.  I include it with my other scripts on my index.html. I load this var into my manager's metadateStore on launch.

I get progressively more sophisticated over time, regenerating it automatically when the server starts, serializing and storing it in browser local storage, etc. Once you realize that metadata is just a JS object, you hold the key to endless. Cleverness.

Comment: Thanks @Ward for the answer. I came up to this conclusion as well. Since the database structure will not change I'm saving the metadata as a string into the application. As I said before, after I digged more into the problem I discovered that getting metadata is not the one that is slow, but the initialisation of the Entity Framework. I'm using Entity Framework 5 now and reading [this](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/396130) I was thinking about updating EF to version 6 rc1. Does breeze support this version?

Comment: Breeze.net, which includes the EFContextProvider, has not been converted or tested for the as yet unreleased EF6. It probably trips on something that has changed. In general, we don't bother until a MS product is just about to release. Too much churn for us to handle and support.

Comment: @Ward: Do you have a code sample of how to manually set metadata so that it will not try to load it from from server? I'm trying to use `const metadataStore: MetadataStore = MetadataStore.importMetadata(metadata); const entityManagerConfig: EntityManagerOptions = {
            serviceName: "http://localhost:63553",
            metadataStore: metadataStore
        }; this.entityManager = new EntityManager(entityManagerConfig);`, but it still makes HTTP call for metadata when executing a query. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the need for loading metadata in a separate network call from server by embedding it in your scripts and providing Breeze with it manually as @Ward suggested.

Here is how (I'm using TypeScript below):

```
import { DataService, EntityManager, MetadataStore, NamingConvention } from "breeze-client";

        // Your metadata object
        const metadata: any = Metadata.value;

        // define the Breeze `DataService` for this app
        const dataService: DataService = new DataService({
            serviceName: "http://localhost:63000",
            hasServerMetadata: false  // don't ask the server for metadata
        });

        // create the metadataStore 
        const metadataStore: MetadataStore = new MetadataStore({
            namingConvention: NamingConvention.camelCase // if you use this convention
        });

        // initialize it from the application's metadata variable
        metadataStore.importMetadata(metadata);

        const entityManagerConfig: EntityManagerOptions = {
            dataService: dataService,
            metadataStore: metadataStore
        };

        this.entityManager = new EntityManager(entityManagerConfig);
```

Now you have an `EntityManager` instance initialized with the metadata and ready to execute queries.

For more informtion, see [official docs](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/metadata-load-from-script.html)